# JavaScript DOM childNodes.length also returning number of text nodes

Tags: javascript, html, dom, html-parsing

In JavaScript DOM, childNodes.length returns the number of both element and text nodes. Is there any way to count only the number of element-only child nodes?

For example, `childNodes.length` of `div#posts` will return 6, when I expected 2:

```
<div id="posts">
    <!-- some comment -->
    <!-- another comment -->
    <div>an element node</div>
    <!-- another comment -->
    <span>an element node</span>
    a text node
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [element.firstChild is returning '<TextNode ...' instead of an Object in FF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299807/element-firstchild-is-returning-textnode-instead-of-an-object-in-ff)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Not directly. Text nodes (including comments and so on) are child nodes.

Your best bet is to iterate over the childNodes array and count up only those nodes with `nodeType == Node.ELEMENT_NODE`. (And write a function to do so.)

Comment: Older versions of IE do not expose `Node` constants, so for compatibility you'll need to use the value of `Node.ELEMENT_NODE` directly, which is `1`.

Comment: @Tim Down Any idea which version of IE began to support these constants? (Say that I only want to support IE7 or above, is that going to work?)

Comment: IE 7 and 8 don't have them. I think IE 9 does.

Comment: @Tim Down Wow, that's pretty late in the game for Microsoft. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 11):

You could use [`Element.children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.children), but IE (up to 8) [seems to consider comment nodes](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t71) too.

Comment: Be aware that `children` support on `documentFragment` is poor in 2014

Answer (score 7):

You can use `document.querySelectorAll('#posts > *')`:

```js
var children = document.querySelectorAll('#posts > *');
console.log('Number of children: ' + children.length);
```

```html
<div id="posts">
    <!-- some comment -->
    <!-- another comment -->
    <div>an element node
        <span>a grand-child node</span>
    </div>
    <!-- another comment -->
    <span>an element node</span>
    a text node
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could filter by [Node.nodeType](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nodeType) (Mozilla's documentation because I think it's a great resource).

Comment: By "filter" do you mean just iterate and count, or is there actually a quick way to filter by a certain condition in JS that I don't know about?

Comment: Yes, just filter programmatically, as you suggested in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Envoking [element.childNodes](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_childNodes.asp) will return a NodeList which **DOES** contain contain text and other ancillary items, where as envoking [element.children](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_children.asp) will return an HTMLCollection object which **DOES NOT** contain text and other ancillary items.

If you must use childNodes, then you must understand that there is a difference between looping through the resulting NodeList using

```
for(i in nodelist)
```

vs

```
for(i = 0 ; i < nodelist.length ; i++)
```

The first method will also retrieve text and other ancillary items.