# Why can't I access `element.firstChild` in this case?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

```js
function setText() {
  // doesn't change... why not!?
  document.getElementById("demo").firstChild.innerHTML = 'changed!';
}

//calling the function with setTimeout to make sure the HTML is loaded
setTimeout(setText, 500);
```

```html
<div id="demo">
  <p>first</p>
  <p>second</p>
</div>
```

I can't seem to be able to change `<p>first</p>` to `<p>changed!</p>`. Why not?

Comment: `firstChild` in this case is a text element representing the whitespace between `<div id="demo">` and `<p>`

Comment: `firstElementChild` will work like a charm

Comment: or even easier ~ `document.querySelector('#demo > *').textContent = 'changed'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [element.firstChild is returning '<TextNode ...' instead of an Object in FF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299807/element-firstchild-is-returning-textnode-instead-of-an-object-in-ff)

Comment: Please log it to the console and track the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whitespace inside elements is considered as text, and text is considered as nodes.

If you change the HTML to:

```
<div id="demo"><p>first</p><p>second</p></div>
```

it works. Try it.

Or you can use node.firstElementChild to ignore leading text, or use a library like jQuery which takes care of this.

Comment: Aaaah! That's interesting. Thank you.

Comment: That’s kind of weird

Comment: @Phil Sure, it can be optimised. But the question was not asking for an optimised solution. It was asking about the concept... and jeprubio explained it well enough for me to understand!

Comment: @Grateful you don't need to accept an answer. If a duplicate is provided, you can vote on it or wait for the community to do so.

Answer (score 1):

On consoling `document.getElementById("demo").firstChild` I get this
[image: snapshot on logging document.getElementById("demo").firstChild].

The highlighted part show empty text. That may be the reason as it is not the first `p` element.

Instead you can use [**firstElementChild**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/firstElementChild)

```js
function setText() {
  document.getElementById("demo").firstElementChild.innerHTML = 'changed!';
}
setTimeout(setText, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="demo">
  <p>first</p>
  <p>second</p>
</div>
```

Comment: `nodeType: 3` is the real tell here, not the content

Answer (score 0):

You can always use `children` method or `querySelector`

```
function SetText(){
  document.getElementById('demo').children[0].textContent = "changed"
}
```

Or

```
function SetText() {
  document.querySelector('#demo > *').textContent = "changed"
}
```

Comment: There's no need to use `:first-child`. `querySelector` is already doing that

Answer (score 0):

Using ".firstChild" will select the whitespace in a div if there is any. In your case there is some. You have two options, either take our the whitespace/newlines or use this function instead...

```
function setText() {
  // doesn't change because the firstChild isn't the <p> element...
  // try using firstElementChild
  document.getElementById("demo").firstElementChild.innerHTML = 'changed!';
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain why and/or how it answers the question. Providing this additional context would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please edit your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.